# Problems with baking the model

Tags: texture-baking, baking

So.. I'm new to Blender, and I try baking the model, and when I baking the model, shading is not displayed on the texture paint.

I tried two baking modes (*Diffuse* and *Combined*) with different settings. But the result was the same.

Material to bake:
[image: material to bake]

Result of the baked *Diffuse* color:
[image: bake result]

Model: [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I tried to download the file, but it seems to be a RAR file containing an OBJ and an MTL file. The files are a few bytes each and seem empty when imported. Even if the files were exported properly, they won't help us figure out the issue. The Blend file will be much more helpful. Please consider uploading it [here](https://blend-exchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for this, I uploaded it.

Comment: Please add a better description of the problem. *"But the result was the same."* is not helpful for the readers. Readers are people who try to help you and people who might have the same problem looking for answers. In its current state, the question is not helpful for anyone and cannot be answered without downloading the file and analyzing it yourself. What is the expected result? What does not work? -- After downloading your file and baking the *Diffuse* color I guess the problem is the missing red color, right? I've added a screenshot of the material. Please do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange file, seems like a bug on the Eevee side: if you try to render in Cycles (or even go to render view) the color is not present (and so it's not baked, as baking uses Cycles engine).

Probably something strange happens when you multiply the mask by 53.6, it's like if the "Clamp" option works with cycles and doesn't work with Eevee, so that red color "bleeds out" in Eevee but it doesn't show in Cycles.

To solve use Cycles in rendering view to rework your node tree, then bake.

In my example a reworked node tree, 3D viewer mode set to "Rendered", Bake working as expected (I raised the world light color and set the samples to 1 in order to get a faster baking).

[image]

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug to me (tested with Blender 3.6.0 and the latest 4.0.2). The bake and render with Cycles is correct but the viewport and render with EEVEE is wrong. There is too much red. The image texture (=color A) has no red at all, and the *Fac* input of the *Mix* node before the *Principled BSDF* has very little white (=color B, red). If you disconnect the image texture and use just 2 colors then it looks correct. If you plug in the image texture again, the entire chest turns red for an unknown reason, which should not be the case.

Comment: thank you, of course, but I don't really understand how this is done.

Comment: How to do it i mean - "To solve use Cycles in rendering view to rework your node tree, then bake." or don't understand something.

Comment: I updated my answer.